# React Native IOS - Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"

Tags: ios, react-native, socket.io

Its my first time when I eject an app built in Expo but I get some strange log when I come back from background in my app and sometimes it gives me Network Error. I also use Socket.IO which I due to this also drops the connection with it

Any idea what it can be and how it should be solved?

```
2021-01-28 15:44:21.919753+0000 client[15322:3152792] BackgroundSession <4FD896C2-975D-48B7-A148-99A86AF85CD1> connection to background transfer daemon interrupted
2021-01-28 15:44:21.922110+0000 client[15322:3152745] BackgroundSession <B895AD11-0ABE-42C6-B1C3-201FE16EE801> connection to background transfer daemon interrupted
2021-01-28 15:44:21.924908+0000 client[15322:3152787] BackgroundSession <4FD896C2-975D-48B7-A148-99A86AF85CD1> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated
2021-01-28 15:44:21.927499+0000 client[15322:3152745] BackgroundSession <B895AD11-0ABE-42C6-B1C3-201FE16EE801> connection to background transfer daemon invalidated
2021-01-28 15:44:21.927135+0000 client[15322:3152694] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C18] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2021-01-28 15:44:21.931216+0000 client[15322:3152694] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C21] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2021-01-28 15:44:21.934258+0000 client[15322:3152694] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am getting the same

Comment: @AnshuKandhari not really. I am still trying to find a solution